# Trying to run foreman on OpenShift, having cartridge issues

Tags: openshift, foreman

Does anyone know why running

```
rhc app create test ruby-2.0 mysql-5.5 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=cantino/openshift-foreman-cartridge
```

works on OpenShift, but running

```
rhc app create test ruby-2.0 mysql-5.5 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=cantino/openshift-foreman-cartridge -s
```

gives the following error:

```
Creating application 'test' ... cantino-foreman-0.63.0 cannot be embedded in scalable app 'test'.
```

I want to be able to run this as a scalable app, so that I can run one gear with MySQL and the other with foreman and passenger (ruby-2.0).

Any help appreciated!  Is my custom cartridge misconfigured?

Comment: It's possible that your Group-Overrides section could be mis-configured.  You might want to check out this part of the guide (http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#group-overrides) and verify that you have foreman co-located with the correct other cartridges

Comment: I tried both `web_proxy` and `foreman`, and neither seemed to work.

Comment: If your cart is forked from another users cart, you might try asking them about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that @ncdc on GitHub was able to solve my issue.

https://github.com/ncdc/openshift-foreman-cartridge/issues/1

We needed to add `plugin` as a category.